# Inject different dependencies to derived classes with dagger

Tags: android, dagger-2

Suppose I have an abstract activity with a dependency:

```
AbstractActivity {
    @Inject
    MyInterface obj;
}
```

And a couple of successors of the activity, say `ActivityOne` and `ActivityTwo`.

I would like these activities to be provided with different implementations of `MyInterface`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Maybe it will be useful for you to check **@Named** annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, however you can do the following

```
public abstract class AbstractActivity {
    protected abstract MyInterface getMyObj();
}
```

And then override this method to return the implementation you inject into your subclass.